# Как создать новую таблицу из данной, в которой будут строки, в которых F(x1,x2,x3) = 1?

Tags: python

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "F(x1,x2,x3)"]
x.add_row([0,0,0,1])
x.add_row([0,0,1,1])
x.add_row([0,1,0,0])
x.add_row([0,1,1,0])
x.add_row([1,0,0,1])
x.add_row([1,0,1,1])
x.add_row([1,1,0,0])
x.add_row([1,1,1,1])
print(x)
```

Comment: что такое `F(x1, x2, x3)`?

Comment: Пример функции (это с дискретной математики).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Numpy:

```
In [38]: import numpy as np   #  pip install numpy

In [39]: a = np.array([[0,0,0,1],
    ...:               [0,0,1,1],
    ...:               [0,1,0,0],
    ...:               [0,1,1,0],
    ...:               [1,0,0,1],
    ...:               [1,0,1,1],
    ...:               [1,1,0,0],
    ...:               [1,1,1,1]])

In [40]: print(a)
[[0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]

In [41]: res = a[a[:, 3] == 1]

In [42]: print(res)
[[0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

или модулем Pandas:

```
In [43]: import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:   [[0,0,0,1],
    ...:   [0,0,1,1],
    ...:   [0,1,0,0],
    ...:   [0,1,1,0],
    ...:   [1,0,0,1],
    ...:   [1,0,1,1],
    ...:   [1,1,0,0],
    ...:   [1,1,1,1]],
    ...:   columns = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "F(x1,x2,x3)"]
    ...: )

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
   x1  x2  x3  F(x1,x2,x3)
0   0   0   0            1
1   0   0   1            1
2   0   1   0            0
3   0   1   1            0
4   1   0   0            1
5   1   0   1            1
6   1   1   0            0
7   1   1   1            1

In [46]: res = df[df['F(x1,x2,x3)']==1]

In [47]: res
Out[47]:
   x1  x2  x3  F(x1,x2,x3)
0   0   0   0            1
1   0   0   1            1
4   1   0   0            1
5   1   0   1            1
7   1   1   1            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the PrettyTable module itself is able to *select only continuous range of rows*, and **not** rows by some condition, you need prepare rows in such a way that you may *select from them in advance, before creating a PrettyTable instance.*

For example, as a list of rows:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable


FIELD_NAMES = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "F(x1,x2,x3)"]

#####  Creating your original table from a list of rows  #####

rows = [
        [0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,1,1],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0],
        [1,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,1],
        [1,1,0,0],
        [1,1,1,1], 
       ]

x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = FIELD_NAMES

for row in rows:
    x.add_row(row)


#####  Creating a new table with selected rows only  #####

selected_rows = [row for row in rows if row[3]] == 1]

y = PrettyTable()
y.field_names = FIELD_NAMES

for row in selected_rows:
    y.add_row(row)


#####  Printing the original and the new tables  #####    

print(x)
print(y)
```